# Is there a way to protect the $_SERVER global from modification?

Tags: php

I would like to prevent php scripts from being able to modify the contents of the `$_SERVER` global.

Specifically I don't want to allow

```
unset $_SERVER['foo'];
```

but it would be nice to forbid any modification, e.g. a module or php.ini declaration.

Is there one?

Comment: I think it would be helpful to know your reason for this.

Answer (score 0):

If you're in control of the root level script you could just copy it:

```
$_my_server = $_SERVER;
```

I think it would be helpful to know your reason for this; the `$_SERVER` variable shouldn't be modified by included scripts, because there's rarely a reason for someone to need to modify it. It's generated at run-time so any changes aren't persisted to subsequent runs of the script.

Also your extra point about `php.ini` declarations is a bit more confusing - the point of many componentes of `$_SERVER` is to inform scripts about those declarations, so having it send fake data would seem a very odd use case and maybe not possible.

Comment: What I'm doing, I keep authentication database with user e-mail and pass hashes in separate database from main web application platform. When the handler that controls that db is sourced, plugins won't be used and vice versa - but a plugin ajax script could, so I'm using SetEnv to set an apache variable on directories that contain plugin ajax scripts - so the authentication db handler can refuse to connect if that is present, but if the ajax script unsets it, then the check fails.

Comment: OK; how does that relate to the `$_SERVER` super global? Are you sure you're not thinking of `$_SESSION`?

Comment: Yes - in the apache DirectoryMatch directive that allows a plugin to have ajax scripts, I am using SetEnv to set a server variable. Thus in my script that loads the authentication database, it can check for the presence of that server variable and exit without loading the authentication database handler. But a simple unset defeats it. Unfortunately one can not define a php constant in an apache DirectoryMatch directive. $_SERVER variable is best we can do.

Comment: Can the script not just check it's own run location using $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; this would provide the same level of clarity as DirectoryMatch without having the modify the server configuration.

Comment: With respect to php.ini - it is because you can use apache to set php.ini settings via php_value so if there was a way to declare $_SERVER can't be modified in php.ini (e.g. with an extension) then I could use php_value after using SetEnv. But it looks like it isn't possible.

Answer (score 0):

Not as far as i'm aware.
If you are relying on the contents of $_SERVER throughout you code, and dont want other code (plugin?) to modify it, your best option is to make a copy during the bootstrap stage of your application, then use that copy throughout your code:

```
$serverDetails = $_SERVER;

$foo = $serverDetails['foo'];
```

Comment: A plugin's ajax scripts are independent of my web application, they only load the parts of the platform they need to - helps keep them fast without running a bunch of un-necessary code just to do something simple. Ah well, I was hoping there was an PECL module or something that could protect _SERVER.

Comment: I suppose I will have to change how it is done and use a wrapper for plugin Ajax that defines a constant and then requires the plugin's ajax rather than using DirectoryMatch to allow plugin ajax scripts.