# Is PHP's $_SERVER superglobal guaranteed to be writeable?

Tags: php

My PHP scripts are able to write to the superglobal array `$_SERVER`.

Whilst messing with `$_SERVER` is pretty obviously a bad idea in almost all cases, there may be situations where it could be useful as a short-term band-aid or for some kinds of testing. Can I rely on it being writeable by scripts, or is this something that might be:

- different for different servers or PHP versions?
- controllable by some ini setting?

The PHP docs don't appear to specify whether `S_SERVER` should be, or might be, read-only. They do imply that it's just a variable, and therefore writeable like any other variable. However, since it's a rather special variable, it seems reasonable to ask the question. It's very easy to show $_SERVER being modified on a real PHP web page:

```
<?php
$uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = "test-value";

echo '<pre>
Before: "'.$uri.'"
After : "'.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].'"
</pre>';

die();
```

Comment: Discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28806835/is-there-a-way-to-protect-the-server-global-from-modification

Comment: It's variable. If it does not exists, `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = "test-value"` will create it

Comment: Are you intending to put things in there that you can then read back in other scripts?

Comment: @JacobMulquin thanks, but it's slightly different: that one is asking "eek, it's a variable, how can I force it to be read-only?" and I'm asking "can I be 100% sure it will never be read-only?".

Comment: @RiggsFolly Only scripts that are `include`d or `require`d. I do of course understand that `$_SERVER` is reconstructed on each new HTTP request.

Comment: The PHP docs explicitly mention that `$GLOBALS` is read-only since 8.1, so I would imagine they would mention something about restricting write access on the other superglobals if that was an available feature. I think it's safe to assume they are writable everywhere.

Comment: @JacobMulquin great comment, thanks. Makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that PHP even *supports* read-only variables at all. The closest thing to an exception is that [you can't wipe out the entire `$GLOBALS` array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php), as in `$GLOBALS = []` (but you can still create or edit individual array elements). And even this restriction does not affect `$_SERVER`, this is totally valid:

```
$_SERVER = 'x';
```

Of course, that doesn't mean that editing a `$_SERVER` entry will necessarily have the same effect than the original value had. For example, `$_SERVER['PATH']` contains the process PATH environment variable, but editing it to a different value will not change the env variable itself:

```
var_dump(getenv('PATH'), $_SERVER['PATH']);
$_SERVER['PATH'] = '/opt/another/';
var_dump(getenv('PATH'), $_SERVER['PATH']);
```

```
string(13) "/usr/bin:/bin"
string(13) "/usr/bin:/bin"
string(13) "/usr/bin:/bin"
string(13) "/opt/another/"
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/S9u1d#v8.2.7)

Comment: I 100% agree with everything you say, but it slightly misses the point of my question, which is whether I can **guarantee** writeability on a variable that clearly is out-of-the-ordinary. It's pretty clear that there is no reason at all to suspect it isn't writeable, and I'm grateful to everyone who showed good reasons why that is probably true.

Comment: Sorry if I missed some point. It's hard to provide evidence of a negative assertion of this kind, since the language will typically not document things it doesn't do, and of course anyone can propose an RFC to change this in future versions, so nothing is guaranteed.

Comment: Please don't apologize, and thanks again for your helpful comments.

Answer (score 1):

All superglobals are writable.

Comment: Is that documented anywhere? Maybe not, because it's "obvious" in some way. And I suppose that the arrival of read-only class properties in PHP8.1 is further proof that it's "obvious" that ordinary variables can't be read-only.

Comment: @JonathanBromley essentially the superglobals are actually just arrays that PHP pre-populates for you. And arrays are writeable, just like any other variable (which isn't part of a class, and having an access modifier, or is otherwise explicitly documented as being readonly).